# <w>[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: No serializer registered for ConcatSource

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, payload-cms

**payload.config.ts**

```
import { buildConfig } from 'payload/config'
import { webpackBundler } from '@payloadcms/bundler-webpack'
import { mongooseAdapter } from '@payloadcms/db-mongodb'
import { slateEditor } from '@payloadcms/richtext-slate'
import path from 'path'
import { Users } from './collections/Users'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env'),
})

export default buildConfig({
  serverURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL || '',
  collections: [Users], 
  routes: {
    admin: '/sell',
  },
  admin: {
    user: 'users',
    bundler: webpackBundler(),
    meta: {
      titleSuffix: '- DigitalHippo',
      favicon: '/favicon.ico',
      ogImage: '/thumbnail.jpg',
    },
  },
  rateLimit: {
    max: 2000,
  },
  editor: slateEditor({}),
  db: mongooseAdapter({
    url: process.env.MONGODB_URL!,
  }),
  typescript: {
    outputFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'payload-types.ts'),
  },
})
```

I'm encountering an issue with Webpack's PackFileCacheStrategy related to serialization. Upon using @payloadcms/bundler-webpack version 1.0.5, I'm receiving the following error:

[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: No serializer registered for ConcatSource

- I expect the bundler to work without throwing the No serializer registered for ConcatSource error.
- 
- I'm using @payloadcms/bundler-webpack version 1.0.5.
- Webpack's PackFileCacheStrategy is throwing an error related to serialization.
- This error occurs when I'm building the project with the specified configuration in payload.config.ts.
- I've also configured other Payload settings (collections, routes, bundler setup, editor options, etc.) as per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace webpackBundler with viteBundler.
(npm i @payloadcms/bundler-vite)

```
import { viteBundler } from "@payloadcms/bundler-vite";
admin: {
    user: "users",
    bundler: viteBundler(),
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same warning after manually changing the `routes.admin` property.
You have it changed too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).